# cannot send ether to a contract address

Tags: contract-invocation

I am on a private net. I try sending ether to a contract address. It just doesn't work.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: "0x39ce9b3b171da836afb02cbe2eff8d4e4fd6f174", 
     value: web3.toWei(3, "ether"), gas:90000000})
```

I did unlock my account. I also run a miner. Increased the gas to other higher values, etc. I really do not know what is wrong with it?

Comment: Did the contract defines a payable function?

Comment: See this FAQ for reference http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html?highlight=payable#what-is-the-deal-with-function-inside-solidity-contracts-how-can-a-function-not-have-a-name

Comment: I don't think that you can transfer ether to any contract address like this. You need to call a function from the contract to handle the sent ether or need to define fallback function.

Comment: Thanks, I added payable keyword to the function and it worked.   function paypremium() public payable  { .....}

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the from with an actual address and see if it work.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: "/* Contact Address*/", to: "0x39ce9b3b171da836afb02cbe2eff8d4e4fd6f174", 
 value: web3.toWei(3, "ether"), gas:90000000})
```